# pg_dump is not working in POstgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am working with PostgreSQL database. I want to dump my database schema in psql file.
i am using following command for that,

```
pg_dump -U postgres -s EspaceDB > D:\espacedb.psql
```

But while i am throwing this query, i am getting error like this,

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "EspaceDB" failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

Please suggest me proper method.

Comment: Please share postgres log files. Also is this a large DB?

Comment: 2018-01-04 15:28:37 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-01-04 15:28:37 IST LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2018-01-04 15:28:37 IST LOG:  invalid record length at 0/2567280: wanted 24, got 0
2018-01-04 15:28:37 IST LOG:  redo is not required
2018-01-04 15:28:37 IST LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2018-01-04 15:28:37 IST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2018-01-04 15:28:37 IST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started

Comment: Do not add additional information as comments. [edit] your question